# Can I read from the beginning a file open for append mode without an initial fseek()?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, fopen, fseek

When an existing non empty file is successfully opened by `fopen()` in `"a+"` or `"ab+"` mode, I should be able to read from it or write to the end without an initial call to `fseek()` or `rewind()`. Does the C Standard specify that an initial read from this file will read from the beginning of the file or should I always set the file position before reading?

The C Standard seems ambiguous as it states in **7.21.5.2 the `fopen` function** that:

> <sub><sup>6.</sup></sub> Opening a file with append mode (`a` as the first character in the `mode` argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the `fseek` function. In some implementations, opening a binary file with append mode (`b` as the second or third character in the above list of `mode` argument values) may initially position the file position indicator for the stream beyond the last data written, because of null character padding.

On those systems where the file position indicator would point at or beyond the last data written, would an initial reading operation fail?

Comment: Looking at the [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html), the update mode `"+"` seems to be a red herring: even for regular read mode `"r"` it is not specified that reading shall start at the beginning (and equivalently for mode `"w"`). It is only implied by reference to the `open` function, which describes the required semantics.]

Comment: @usr: I am not sure what you mean, if the file is open for update mode, both reading and writing are possible. The question is whether a read operation issued just after the `fopen()` will read from the beginning of the file or attempt to read from the end of file and probably fail. More precisely, if `rewind()` is required to ensure reading takes place from the beginning of the file. The specification for this is not in the description of the `fopen()` function.

Comment: @usr: indeed I was asserting that reading was a defined operation. It is implementation defined where the initial reading will start, hence setting the file position explicitly seems necessary in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is implementation defined:

> **7.21.3 Files**
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup></sub> A stream is associated with an external file (which may be a physical device) by opening a file, which may involve creating a new file. Creating an existing file causes its former contents to be discarded, if necessary. If a file can support positioning requests (such as a disk file, as opposed to a terminal), then a file position indicator associated with the stream is positioned at the start (character number
> zero) of the file, unless the file is opened with append mode in which case it is implementation-defined whether the file position indicator is initially positioned at the beginning or the end of the file. The file position indicator is maintained by subsequent reads, writes, and positioning requests, to facilitate an orderly progression through the file.

So a call to `rewind()` or `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET)` is required before an initial read from the beginning of a file open for update mode/write to the end, as determined by a mode string starting with `"a+"` or `"ab+"`.

Comment: @usr: OK, the question was *Does the C Standard specify that a initial read from this file will read from the beginning of the file or should I always set the file position before reading?*, I will update the title